# Converting a list of unequally shaped arrays to Tensorflow 2 Dataset: ValueError: Can't convert non-rectangular Python sequence to Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have tokenized data in the form of a list of **unequally shaped** arrays:

```
array([array([1179,    6,  208,    2, 1625,   92,    9, 3870,    3, 2136,  435,
          5, 2453, 2180,   44,    1,  226,  166,    3, 4409,   49, 6728,
         ...
         10,   17, 1396,  106, 8002, 7968,  111,   33, 1130,   60,  181,
       7988, 7974, 7970])], dtype=object)
```

With their respective targets:

```
Out[74]: array([0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1], dtype=object)
```

I'm trying to transform them into a padded `tf.data.Dataset()`, but it won't let me convert unequal shapes to a tensor. I will get this error:

```
ValueError: Can't convert non-rectangular Python sequence to Tensor.
```

The full code is here. Assume that my starting point is after `y = ...`:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import numpy as np

(train_data, test_data) = tfds.load('imdb_reviews/subwords8k',
                                    split=(tfds.Split.TRAIN, tfds.Split.TEST),
                                    as_supervised=True)

x = np.array(list(train_data.as_numpy_iterator()))[:, 0]
y = np.array(list(train_data.as_numpy_iterator()))[:, 1]


train_tensor = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x.tolist(), y))\
    .padded_batch(batch_size=8, padded_shapes=([None], ()))
```

What are my options to turn this into a **padded batch** tensor?

Comment: What about https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/sequence/pad_sequences ?

Comment: Yeah that worked I don't know why I didn't think of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your data is stored in Numpy arrays or Python lists, then you can use [`tf.data.Dataset.from_generator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_generator) method to create the dataset and then pad the batches:

```
train_batches = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    lambda: iter(zip(x, y)), 
    output_types=(tf.int64, tf.int64)
).padded_batch(
    batch_size=32,
    padded_shapes=([None], ())
)
```

However, if you are using `tensorflow_datasets.load` function, then there is no need to use `as_numpy_iterator` to separate the data and the labels, and then put them back together in a dataset! That's redundant and inefficient. The objects returned by `tensorflow_datasets.load` are already an instance of `tf.data.Dataset`. So, you just need to use `padded_batch` on them:

```
train_batches = train_data.padded_batch(batch_size=32, padded_shapes=([None], []))
test_batches = test_data.padded_batch(batch_size=32, padded_shapes=([None], []))
```

Note that in TensorFlow 2.2 and above, you no longer need to provide the `padded_shapes` argument if you just want all the axes to be padded to the longest of the batch (i.e. default behavior).

Comment: The reasoning for that is when I do a real task, I won't have a convenient TFDS object. It's more likely that I will have a list of list/arrays, and the targets separately. This is why I said "Assume that my starting point is after y = ...". Thanks for informing me of this update.

Comment: @NicolasGervais Oh, sorry! I did not pay enough attention to that. Please take a look at my updated answer for a solution for the case when your data is stored in Numpy arrays/Python lists.

Comment: @NicolasGervais Didn't the solution for Numpy array work for you?

Comment: The project is on hold, I'll try this out once it's resumed, and I'll get back to you then.

Comment: Why don't you participate in the Keras tag anymore?

Comment: @NicolasGervais Well, one reason is the lack of enough time on my side and the other one is the lack of good interesting questions being asked here. Naturally, as ML and TF/Keras has become popular, more and more people are using it and therefore the percentage of newbie, duplicate, poor or please-debug-it-for-me questions have increased. Both of these reasons have reduced my motivation for answering questions in Keras tag and I have stopped monitoring this tag. Although, from time to time, people reach out to me via email with their question and I'll try to help them as much as I can.

Comment: @Nicolas Gervais can you help me in this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74251623/how-to-solve-valueerror-cant-convert-non-rectangular-python-sequence-to-tensor